# In laravel 5.5/vue.js appication to use jquery-confirm library

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jquery-confirm

In laravel 5.5/vue.js appication I would like to use jquery-confirm library and for this
In my resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php I wrote:

```
    ...
            @yield('content')
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/funcs.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/my_app.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery/jquery-confirm.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

But in console I got the error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.confirm is not a function
```

Was it wrong way of attaching files to the app?
Which is the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: generally you need to ensure you're including `jquery-confirm` after you've included jquery which afaik is included in `app.js`

Answer (score 4):

The way I recommend doing this is:

Install jquery-confirm via NPM, simplest thing to do is to add it in your package.json under dependencies, e.g.:

```
"dependencies": {
      ...
      "jquery-confirm": "^3.3.2" 
 }
```

Then require it in your `app.js` after jquery

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('jquery-confirm');
```

The next time your compile the package it should be included in your app.js

If you insist on including it in your source then one of the following would work:

1. Make sure the file is in your `/resources/assets/js` folder. Then update your `webpack.mix.js` to the following:

   ```
   mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
       .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
       .copy('resources/assets/js/jquery-confirm.min.js', 'public/css/jquery-confirm.min.js');
   ```

**OR**

2. Make sure the file is in your `/public/js` folder

By doing either of those you also need to make sure the file is loaded after `app.js` :

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery/jquery-confirm.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: apokryfos, Thanks for response, that was helpfull!
Could you also to figure which is the best way to include jquery-confirm.min.css to the project?

Comment: I've updated the question. I still thing the NPM route is better though